# Timeout exception while displaying interstitial ad in emulator

Tags: android, admob, interstitial

I am trying to display Interstitial test ad in emulator. Everytime when i try to display i am getting an error saying "The interstitial has not loaded" and below exception.

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
                                                  at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzajy.get(Unknown Source:32)
                                                  at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzajg.zza(Unknown Source:19)
                                                  at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzabh.zza(Unknown Source:700)
                                                  at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzabh.zzb(Unknown Source:4)
                                                  at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzabj.run(Unknown Source:5)
                                                  at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzagn.call(Unknown Source:2)
                                                  at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzago.run(Unknown Source:9)
                                                  at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:457)
                                                  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
                                                  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
                                                  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
                                                  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
                                               Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
                                                  at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzajk.run(Unknown Source:4)
                                                  at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:457)
                                                  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
                                                  at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:301)
                                                  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162) 
                                                  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636) 
                                                  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

I declared ad like below.

```
 private void ad() {
    mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
    mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712");
    mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
 }

private void showInterstitial() {
     mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
        public void onAdLoaded() {
            if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
                mInterstitialAd.show();
                AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
                mInterstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

whenever I want to display ad i am calling `showInterstitial()`. I tried only with `mInterstitialAd.show()` also but no ads shown. what is wrong here? I tried without the adlistener also.

How I am showing ad

```
   movie.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    showInterstitial();
                    Intent s = new Intent(UserProfile.this,moviesearchrequest.class);
                    s.putExtra("from","wanted");
                    startActivity(s);
                    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_up, R.anim.slide_out_up);
                }
            });
```

Comment: you are loading another view and before that showing interstitial ad might be causing this problem. Can you comment intent code and see if that removes timeoutexception

Comment: on a different note.. showing full screen on page load is disallowed interstitial implementation https://support.google.com/admob/answer/6201362?hl=en